# How to seed database once with multiple views for consistent data

Tags: ember-cli-mirage

I might be thinking about mock APIs incorrectly, but I figured it was worth asking.

I am trying to create an object with a basic view and a detailed view, for example "basic-author" and "detailed-author". But, I would like each object to return consistent data. For example, properties like "author_name" should be the same for basic-author and detailed-author.

I am currently trying to accomplish this by generating a list of authors and extending it:

```
// mirage/scenarios/default.js
server.createList('author', 20);

// mirage/config.js
this.get('/basic-author', (schema) => {
  return schema.basicAuthors.all();
});

// mirage/factories/author.js
import { Factory, faker } from 'ember-cli-mirage';
export default Factory.extend({
  // bunch of properties, like author_name
});

// mirage/factories/basic-author.js, mirage/factories/detailed-author.js
import Author from './author';

export default Author.extend({
});
```

But, obviously, this won't work because getting all basicAuthors returns nothing because there are no "basic-author" in the database. If I try to change the routes to return all authors, my ember models won't work because it is returning a list of 20 authors, which is the incorrect model type.

I have also tried setting the faker seed, but that makes every item the same.

Comment: If this is not possible, I have also been told to not worry about my mock data to have consistent data, and create two separate lists for "basic-author" and "detailed-author".

Answer (score 0):

The best way to accomplish this is to use Factory traits. [Give the docs](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.4.x/factories/#traits) a read, then you should be able to set up something like this:

```
// mirage/factories/author.js
import { Factory, trait, faker } from 'ember-cli-mirage';

export default Factory.extend({
  authorName() {
    return faker.name.firstName();
  },
  age: 10,

  withDetails: trait({
    email() {
      return `${this.authorName}@gmail.com`;
    },
    ssn: 123456789
  })

});
```

Then in tests/dev you can create a basic authors like this

```
server.create('author');
server.createList('author', 20);
```

and detailed authors like this:

```
server.create('author', 'withDetails');
server.createList('author', 20, 'withDetails');
```

Comment: Thanks Sam, would I be able to dynamically return the traits though? This doesn't really meet my use case because it does not return the same author via "basic-author" and the same author with extra detail via "detailed-author". If I were to click from a basic-author view into a detailed-author view, the authorName would be different.

Comment: In this case I would expect the XHR request to have an `id` associated with it, in which case you could use `schema.users.find(4)` (for example) to retrieve the relevant author. Different route handlers can use different serializers too, so your route handler for `get('/authors/:id')` could use the detailed-author view.